# Masked Edit two code formats for a single input text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mask

I have two masks G999-9  and H99-9 which stand for graduates and honor which both need to be entered for a single input text html control.

While first typing, if it hits a G I would like it to show the format for the Graduate format, and for the Honors, I would like it to show the format for the Honors format while typing it out.  Is there a simple way to do this in javascript or jQuery?

Examples:

```
G111-1
H91-5
G001-3
G___-_  (If you hit G it should show the Graduate format)
H__-_   (If you hit H it should show the Honors format.)
____-_  (Type anything else, or nothing do this.)
```

Thanks,
Marc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Regex Based Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sEt5c/1)**

Yay! regex! Yes, like every other (non-HTML) parsing questions there's a regex for that. :)

```
$("input").keyup(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode > 40 || e.keyCode < 37)
    {
        var validInput = $(this).val().match(/(([G])(([0-9]{3}[-]([0-9]{0,1})?|[0-9]{0,3})?)?|([H])(([0-9]{2}[-]([0-9]{0,1})?|[0-9]{0,2})?)?)/);
        $(this).val(validInput?validInput[0]:"")
    }
});
```

It's a bit convoluted (help in optimizing it would be much appreciated), but it works.

Comment: +1 not only for taking the time to build the regex, but for helping illustrate my point that the regex would be nasty.  : )

Comment: @John Green Agreed XD but it's so fun! It's almost like a math puzzle XD

Comment: I really want this to apply to show the format after erroring out.  It would be cool if the format is left and the person typing types over the actual format as they type.  Usually the format is erased the instant someone starts typing.

Answer (score 2):

Simple way?  You're either going to have to walk the string or use some fancy regex.

Normally, we'd use regexes for this, but with the assumption that you don't know so much about regexes (perhaps a bad assumption, but most people that can read them will gravitate towards them first) and in the hopes of keeping you following what is happening, I wrote it more procedurally:

```
<input type="text" class="formatted" />

$(document).ready(function(){
    function applyMask(instr){
        var pOut = [],  delimitter = '-', format = 0, pSplit = 4, pMax = 6;
        // There are a lot of ways to express this.  I just chose one that should
        // be understandable.
        if ((instr.length > 0) && (instr[0].toUpperCase() == 'H'))
        {
            pSplit = 3;
            pMax = 5;
        } 
        pMax = Math.min(pMax, instr.length);

        for (var i=0; i < pMax; i++)
        {
            if ((i==pSplit) && (instr[i] != delimitter))
            {
                pOut.push(delimitter);
            }
            else
            {
                pOut.push(instr[i]);
            }
        }
        return pOut.join('');
    }

    $('.formatted').keyup(function(){
        $(this).val(applyMask($(this).val()).toUpperCase());
    });
});
```

Here's a fiddle, even:  http://jsfiddle.net/UdcND/

Answer (score 2):

There are some jQuery plugins for easily converting a text input to a mask edit:

- **a simple but useful plugin:** http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/js/mask/
- **another good option:** http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/